# How to get a file name from a directory using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, flash

I'm trying to update an old flash gallery site of mine using php. I'm wondering how I can get a file name randomly from the folder that stores all of the flashs after the original flash has been middle mouse clicked. I'm new to php and I feel as if I have some things mixed up and I have gaps in my knowledge.

HTML

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div id="flash-container">
    <object id="flash-content" data="swfs/sunshine.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
    </div>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

PHP

```
<?php
function random_flash($dir = 'swfs')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}
?>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flash-content").on('click', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET"
            , url: "flash.php"
            , data: {
                fileName: "$file"
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
        if (e.which == 2) {
            e.preventDefault();
            flash - container.innerHTML = '<object id="flashcontent" data="' + $file + '">' + '<param name="movie" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">' + '</object>';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I middle click on the existing flash object it should look into the 'swfs' folder and randomly select a name when the name is selected it should change the innerHTML of the flash itself to insert the file name so to go to the next flash

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use javascript at all with the name insertion and I should just use php for it......

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some error on your code.

If you call php, even in a javascript code ... you need to use `<?php` and `?>`.

On your javascript code, I can see `$file`. Okay, but what is it ?
Should be `<?php echo $file; ?>` no ?

And in your JS code : `flash - container.innerHTML`
What is the object `flash` ? You can't substract object like this :) (Typo error ?)

---

So:

1. On your html web page randered, open the Console Editor and check if tehre is any error.
2. Open the source code of the page and check if the html/javascript seems good. If you are php error -> check the php code.

> You can also and somewhere a `<?php echo $file; ?>` or `<?php echo random_flash(); ?>` to check if the value return is a file and the expected value.